# MSSQL: Use the result of nested sub-queries

Tags: nested, subquery

The following works and results in the output shown in the image below.

```
SELECT 
    SU_Internal_ID,
    NQ_QuestionText,
    NA_AnswerText,
    NoOfTimesChoosen 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
        U.SU_Internal_ID,
        NQ.NQ_QuestionText,
        NA.NA_AnswerText,
        COUNT(PC.UserID) AS NoOfTimesChoosen 
    FROM [dbo].[ParticipantNSChoices] PC 
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[KnowledgeSurveyAnswers] NA 
        on PC.NA_Internal_ID = NA.NA_Internal_ID 
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[KnowledgeSurveyQuestions] NQ 
        on PC.NQ_Internal_ID = NQ.NQ_Internal_ID 
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[AspNetUsers] U 
        on PC.UserID = U.Id 
    WHERE 
        U.SU_Internal_ID=1 
        and NQ.NQ_QuestionText LIKE '%Do you feel comfortable working with computers%' 
    GROUP 
        BY U.SU_Internal_ID,
        NQ.NQ_QuestionText,
        NA.NA_AnswerText ) as A
```

I want to add a column to show the percent for the two answers 'No' and 'Yes': so next to 'No' I want '20' and next to 'Yes' '80', but I'm pretty new at this and am stuck; I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

[Result of working script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqUq7.png)

Comment: hi @rolando, please format correctly your SQL code to help us to understand it! thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the outer SELECT.

```
SELECT 
    U.SU_Internal_ID,
    NQ.NQ_QuestionText,
    NA.NA_AnswerText,
    COUNT(PC.UserID) AS NoOfTimesChoosen,
    (cast(COUNT(PC.UserID) as float) / 
        cast(
            (select count(*) from [dbo].[ParticipantNSChoices] PC2 
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[KnowledgeSurveyAnswers] NA2 on PC2.NA_Internal_ID = NA2.NA_Internal_ID 
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[KnowledgeSurveyQuestions] NQ2 on PC2.NQ_Internal_ID = NQ2.NQ_Internal_ID 
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[AspNetUsers] U2 on PC2.UserID = U2.Id 
                WHERE 
                    U2.SU_Internal_ID=1 
                    and NQ2.NQ_QuestionText LIKE '%Do you feel comfortable working with computers%' ) 
            as float)) 
            * 100 as PercentChosen
FROM [dbo].[ParticipantNSChoices] PC 
INNER JOIN [dbo].[KnowledgeSurveyAnswers] NA 
    on PC.NA_Internal_ID = NA.NA_Internal_ID 
INNER JOIN [dbo].[KnowledgeSurveyQuestions] NQ 
    on PC.NQ_Internal_ID = NQ.NQ_Internal_ID 
INNER JOIN [dbo].[AspNetUsers] U 
    on PC.UserID = U.Id 
WHERE 
    U.SU_Internal_ID=1 
    and NQ.NQ_QuestionText LIKE '%Do you feel comfortable working with computers%' 
GROUP 
    BY U.SU_Internal_ID,
    NQ.NQ_QuestionText,
    NA.NA_AnswerText
```

The `counts` will be `integers`, so you need to `cast` as `floats` before dividing.  You can then further format to your liking.  Also, I might not have your exact denominator, because I don't know what your data looks like, but you can modify to match what you need.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much Joe, that was really fast. I didn't expect an answer for days!   I tried your suggested code and it worked other than the returned percentages are 0.401606425702811 and 1.60642570281124; that would be the ratio of 2 to 8. I'll see if I can figure out how to get the 20 and 80 I'm looking for. Thanks again!

Comment: @rolando - This is what I meant when i said I didn't know what your data looked like.  I just assumed it was all one-to-one joins.  Instead of just doing a select count(*) on [dbo].[ParticipantNSChoices], you probably need to join in [dbo].[KnowledgeSurveyAnswers] and [dbo].[KnowledgeSurveyQuestions] and [dbo].[AspNetUsers] to get a more accurate count of your total population/universe.

Comment: @rolando - if this answer meets your needs, please close out the question by selecting this answer.

Comment: Thanks Joe; I'm surpirsed you got as far as you did without seeing my tables etc. I'm going to try and figure this out myself, this old dog needs to learn. But I may come back and if I do, I'll put more info out :)

Comment: That table [ParticipantNSChoices] has 498 rows in total. We have selected the correct 2 I am interested using  (NQ.NQ_QuestionText LIKE '%Do you feel comfortable working with%').

What I need to do is calculate the percentages the two rows represent of the total of the two rows: 
 In column ‘NoOfTimesChoosen’, the two rows  have 2 and 8 respectively for a total of 10. I would like column ‘PercentChosen’ to be 20 and 80.
So, the denominator needs to be the sum of the ‘NoOfTimesChoosen’ for the two rows (of the 498).

Comment: I tried by adding this SELECT to the top and aliasing the initial result as 'Rez', but get 'Invalid Object Name 'Rez':  
SELECT AnswerText, NoOfTimesChoosen, (NoOfTimesChoosen * 100) /  (SELECT SUM(NoOfTimesChoosen) FROM Rez) AS Perc
FROM (  ... your code ...

 ) AS Rez

Comment: @rolando - Is this question still open?  Sorry I missed your last comment.  It's difficult debugging SQL in these comments... please post your entire SQL Select command so we can get the full picture.

Comment: @rolando - I just edited my answer...  I believe this will get you closer to what you want.   This is the basic way of doing it in one SQL statement, but there is some duplicate code, so there is probably a more efficient way of getting this done, like inside a stored proc with dynamic SQL, or maybe even with a CTE.

Comment: Thanks Joe; I finally got it running ... I appreciate your efforts!